# How to replace search time with "time" field in fluentbit?

Tags: fluent-bit

I defined a customized multiline parser with regex and another parser to split time and log line into fields "time" and "message" respectively:
[image]

How could I replace the search time with the value of "time"?

Here is my multiline parser, invoked with tail input:

```
[MULTILINE_PARSER]
name          jsm
type          regex
flush_timeout 1000
# rules |   state name  | regex pattern                  | next state
# ------|---------------|--------------------------------------------
rule      "start_state"   "/(\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d+[\+\-]\d+)(.*)/"  "cont"
rule      "cont"          "/^[\s+at|java|Caused]/"            "cont"
```

Here is the parser:

```
[PARSER]
Name jsm
Format regex
Regex /^(?<time>\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d+[\+\-]\d+) (?<message>.*)/m
```

The parser above is invoked in Filter:

```
[FILTER]
name             parser
match            *
key_name         log
parser           jsm
```

Thanks.

Try to find a solution to complete this search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed after adding a parameter Time_Format in Parser jsm, this has to match the time format in the log entry, otherwise it will be ignored.